# "Bus error: 10" When attempting to read IPv4 address from C program arguments

Tags: c, unix, server, tcp

I'm making a TCP server and client, and as part of the server program it needs to take an IPv4 address and port number as arguments at the function call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>  
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Incorrect number of arguments.\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        fprintf(stdout, "Arguments good\n");
    }
    char *ip;
    memset(ip, 0, sizeof(char) * 15);
    ip = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
    strcpy(ip, argv[1]); 
    int portNo = atoi(argv[2]);

    fprintf(stdout, "IP: %s Port: %d\n", ip, portNo);
    
    free(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it in the terminal however (`./myServer 127.0.0.1 50000`), I get `bus error: 10`
I assume I'm doing something wrong allocating memory for ip or copying argv[1] into ip, but I haven't been able to figure out what.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please copy&paste your code into the question. This code will not compile because `ip` is undefined when used in `memset`

Comment: @Gerhardh Ah yes, silly mistake on my part. I've amended that in the question, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the cause of the bus error, as it is still happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ip` is uninitialized when you pass it to `memset`, so you're dereferencing an invalid pointer.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in this case causes a crash.

Allocate the memory first, *then* clear it:

```
char *ip = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
memset(ip, 0, sizeof(char) * 15);
```

Better yet, do both at once:

```
char *ip = calloc(15, sizeof(char));
```

Also, you're not allocating enough space, as an IP such as 192.168.100.100 needs a 16 byte buffer.

```
char *ip = calloc(16, sizeof(char));
```

Better yet, use `INET_ADDRSTRLEN`, defined in netinet/in.h:

```
char *ip = calloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: BTW: the `memset` is useless here, as `strcpy` overwrites it anyway.

Comment: @dbush This worked, thank you very much. I clearly need to learn more about memory allocation :-)